# How do I remove PATH typo in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, path, export

I am taking a class where we are installing DFX and Homebrew via the command line using Ubuntu.  I was supposed to issue the command as follows

commandline:~$export PATH=$PATH:/home/brianw/bin/dfx

Accidentally I issued this while following the instructors example.

commandline:~$export PATH=$PATH:/home/angela/bin/dfx

Now when I issue the command

echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"

I see both the correct one and the mistake.  I would  love to know how to remove the incorrect
one and also so I can do this in the future if needed.  Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Close the terminal emulator and open it again.

Comment: Ok, that worked, thank you! I am confused why this worked and why it showed all the paths correct and incorrect before closing and reopening the terminal emulator.  I would love to know why this works this way?

Comment: Because variables are not saved anywhere. As soon as you exit the shell process, they are gone.